# Automated popup for internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, popup

Unfortunately, my website cannot be displayed optimally when using the Internet Explorer browser.
So I would like make an automated popup only if a user opens my page with the Internet Explorer browser.

Can anyone give me some advices on how to do so?

Thanks!

Best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You could using javascript to detect browser version, if IE then open a popup. The javascript code is like below:

```
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

    var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
    if (trident > 0) {
        // IE 11
        alert("Please use other browsers. We don't support IE.")
    }
```